# Why does CONVERT(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 110) work?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) when converting to/from a `DATETIME` style 110 is USA `mm-dd-yyyy`, however from experimentation this style also works for `yyyy-mm-dd`. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because `yyyy-mm-dd` is unambiguous when converting from text to datetime.

Comment: You will get the first format while using varchar in convert. when you use datetime in convert you will get the second format.

Comment: @DavidG `yyyy-mm-dd` is unambiguous when converting to `DATE`, not `DATETIME` (`yyyymmdd` is unambiguous for both though). Though the answer is probably something among those lines, since the input that op is using is not a valid `110` style, the conversion is probably using a default valid one

Comment: @DavidG It doesn't work for all styles though (eg, 103), nor if I leave out the style altogether.

Comment: @Lamak Why not DATETIME?

Comment: @JamieKitson Works for me if I use 103.

Comment: @DavidG Do you have an ambiguous DD? ie, Try > 12.

Comment: @JamieKitson Hmm, interesting. Just reinforces why I stay away from using `CONVERT` at all!

Comment: @DavidG why is that?, no need to avoid convert if you use valid inputs

Comment: @JamieKitson well, the `103` style is `dd/mm` and 110 is `mm-dd`, so I'm guessing that when using a `yyyy-mm-dd` input when month and day are ambiguous (`2014-11-03`), then when using the `103` style it assumes 11 as the day and 03 as the month and when using the `110` style it assumes 11 as the month and 03 as the day

Comment: @Lamak The point being that it doesn't work for 103.

Comment: @JamieKitson What do you mean that it doesn't work?, exactly which query with which values and what is the exact result that you get?

Comment: @Lamak I like my dates to be in a date format before they hit the database if possible. I dislike `CONVERT` due to it's limited number of possible formats.

Comment: @DavidG Of course that when storing dates you use an appropiate data type, but the thing to avoid is that, not using `CONVERT`.

Comment: @Lamak Exactly, getting the right data in to the DB, as a by product you generally avoid CONVERTing and CASTing, or worse, nasty string manipulation.